# JPA Audit entity direct query

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to query audit entity in my JPA environment.

At first I do `AuditQuery` and it works well, but now I need more advance query witch I can't do with `AuditQuery`.

Now I need something like

```
 this.em.createQuery("FROM ENTITY_AUD").getResultList();
```

but I get error :

```
 QuerySyntaxException: ENTITY_AUD is not mapped [ENTITY_AUD]
```

I understand that this is due that I don't have entity with all properties, but I don't want to have entity because it is audit entity.

Is there a way around it? For me it would be ok to get List of Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create native SQL query in JPA. Replace `createQuery` with `createNativeQuery` in your code:

```java
List<Object[]> list = 
    this.em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM ENTITY_AUD").getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a NamedQuery in your Audit class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_AUD")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Audit.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Audit a")})
public class Audit implements Serializable {
         ...
}
```

then use the named query

```
List<Audit> auditList = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Audit.findAll").getResultList();
```

Read : [Implementing a JPA Named Query](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/ent30qry001.htm)

Comment: Yes I know this solution, but as I described in question I don't wan't to have @Entity because it is audit entity so this would be a almost duplicated entity as original one.